# InvalidArgumentError： You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,1339,2560,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm a rookie to tensorflow, and I get the following error when using keras:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,1339,2560,1]
```

because in my model:

```
model = Model(input=inputs, output=conv13).
```

The input size is `[?,1339,2560,1]` and the output size is `[?,1328,2560,1]` after cropping, so I want to use pad in numpy to make up for the difference:

```
sess=tf.Session()   
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())  
conv12_ar = conv12.eval(session=sess)   
conv13_tem = np.pad(conv12_ar, ((0, 0),(5, 6), (0, 0), (0, 0)), 'edge')  
conv13 = tf.convert_to_tensor(conv13_tem)
```

and I get the error above, can anyone help me? or indicate another way to make up the difference

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are trying to treat tensorflow as a procedural language and not declarative. It's almost always a bug if you have tensorflow statements after you've created your session, and among the most common errors. You haven't posted quite enough of your code to make out exactly where the issue is though.

It appears that you are using numpy to do the padding, so the result of the padding operation should be passed into a `sess.run` call, and you should not need a session to do anything here.

Also, you can simply add the padding step to the tensorflow graph, so take the input in shape `[?, 1328, 2560, 1]`, then right after the definition of the `tf.placeholder` use `tf.pad` to pad it. Then make sure the placeholder is expecting the smaller form and everything should work.

I always recommend creating a `build_graph()` function where you put all your tensor and OP definitions. You should never create any tensorflow constructs after opening the session. Think of tensorflow as having 2 phases: (1) you build a graph of the operations you want to use, then (2) you pass data into the graph (the placeholders) and ask for various values to be computed (`sess.run`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't know there is tf.pad function, I'll try to figure this out.